# ParseFacebookUtils not recognised on android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login, parsefacebookutils

I added Parse-1.9.1.jar to my libs folder and compiled it in my build.gradle file in my app folder. But when i try to initialise parseFacebookUtil, it is not recognised. I dont know why.Below is my build.gradlr. Please help me find out what am missing, thanks

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    compile fileTree('src/main/libs')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
```

Try

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar')
```

instead. Dunno why it would work, but I had the same problem and that solved it for me. If that doesn't help, does the gradle sync/build properly without the ParseFacebook.... line?